# Using setValue:forKey to convert RESTful JSON objects to Application Objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, rest, key-value-coding

Using `setValue:forKey` to convert Application Objects

In my application I created a Patient class (subclass of NSObject)

The JSON object for patient is like below

```
{
"id":1,
"firstName":"Angel ",
"lastName":"Merkel",
"dob":"1989-08-31",
"address":"12 th, Cross street,"
"email":"merkal@gmail.com",
"cellNumber":"213-52578522”,
”ssn":"","maritalStatus":null,
"state":null,
"regularSmoker":false
}
```

so I created the Properties in **patient.h** listed below like both the JSON attribute name and property name are same (so that I can use `setValueForKey`)

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)int idValue;// we cant declare property with name id
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *firstName;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *lastName;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSDate *dob;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *email;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *cellNumber;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *ssn;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *maritalStatus;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *state;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *regularSmoker;
```

And I use `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` method to convert a single JSON object to single Application patient Object

**While converting I have to handle the below two problems**

**Problem 1** Prepare to handle setvalueForUnIdentified key if any unwanted data sent from server

```
-(void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSLog(@"tried to set %@ for Object %@",key,self);
    [self.undefinedKeyValues setValue:value forKey:key]; // so that the unexpected key:value pairs stored
}
```

**Problem 2** Converting to Convenient datatype in application from JSON objects like

- `NSString` to `NSDate` type Object for key “dob”
- `NSNumber` to `int' type for Key “id”

like below code

```
-(void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if([key isEqualToString:@“id”])
    {
        self.idValue=[value intValue];
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@"gender"])
    {
        _gender=value;
       // Problem 2 handled
        if([value isEqualToString:@"Male"]) 
        {
            self.genderType=MALE;


        }
        else if ([value isEqualToString:@"Female"])
        {
            self.genderType=FEMALE;

        }
    }
    else if ([key isEqualToString:@“dob”])
    {
        /// convert the value to NSDate and assign
    }
    else
    {
        [super setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
}
```

My Question is that, can I use the above way to convert the JSON object to application object?

Comment: What's this question about: style, security, correctness? What kind of answer are you expecting? Probably not a single YES or NO. So is it about opinion?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I asking in terms for code Maintainability . I just want to know if I can use setValue:forKey is for the process of converson to application Object . My seniors way of converson is like              object.propname=[dictionary objectForKey:@"key1"];object.propname2=[dictionary objectForKey:@"key2"];......           and going on, this one looks very obvious to new coder at sight what is done, That's why I post the question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a look at [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle). It has the same logic on KVC and can make your life much easier :)